# How to get column value from Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datarow

I'm trying to get row values from a datatable with column value matching the user input.

I found this link:

[How to get a specific column value from a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2916583/1270384)

But I'm not sure about it because I want to be able to say

```
where userID =@userinput and DateBooked =@DateBooked and 
RoomQty=@RoomQty and NoofNights=@NoofNights
```

.

Would this example work for my situation?

Comment: @userimput contains the user input correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to follow the example in the link provided.

Suppose your have a DataTable like this

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("UserID");
            dt.Columns.Add("FullName");
            dt.Columns.Add("DateBooked");
            dt.Columns.Add("RoomQty");
            dt.Columns.Add("NoofNights");

            dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Doe", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date, 2, 3);
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Jack Sparrow", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14).Date, 1, 1);
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Arthur Wilson", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10).Date, 2, 2);
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "Amy Jackson", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).Date, 4, 2);
            dt.Rows.Add(5, "Tim Lee", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date, 1, 5);
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Jack Sparrow", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).Date, 3, 2);
```

and your input parameters are

```
            int userInput = 2;
            DateTime dateBooked = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14).Date;
            int roomQty = 1;
            int noOfNights = 1;
```

You can get the `'FullName'` column value like this (provided you will have a single record based on your where conditions)

```
            string FullName = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                               where Convert.ToInt32(dr["UserID"]) == userInput &&
                               Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateBooked"]) == dateBooked &&
                               Convert.ToInt32(dr["RoomQty"]) == roomQty &&
                               Convert.ToInt32(dr["NoofNights"]) == noOfNights
                               select (string)dr["FullName"]).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<String> userNames =
    dataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row =>
        row.Field<Int32>("userID") == userinput &&
        row.Field<DateTime>("DateBooked") == dateBooked &&
        row.Field<Int32>("RoomQty") == roomQty &&
        row.Field<Int32>("NoofNights") == noofNights)
    .Select(row => row.Field<String>("userName"));
```